# Tikz: Node-label distance depends on way label is added?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

It seems that the distance between a node and its label depends on the way the label is inserted:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
        \node[above]  at (1,1) {A};
        \node[label=above:B] at (1,1) {};   
        \node[left]  at (3,2) {C};
        \node[label=left:D] at (3,2) {};    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which creates this:[image]

If I specify the `label distance` option, it seems only B and D are affected.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=3mm]
        \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
        \node[above]  at (1,1) {A};
        \node[label=above:B] at (1,1) {};   
        \node[left]  at (3,2) {C};
        \node[label=left:D] at (3,2) {};    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I am aware that, for instance, `\node[left]` implicity creates a new node to the left of the coordinates specified. How can I control the distance at which this node is created, so that whichever syntax is used, the distance is the same?

Comment: Why are you not using `\node[above, label=above:B]  at (1,1) {A};`?

Comment: you should not mix node distance and label distance. for example, node above some coordinate has distance from this coordinate equal to `outer sep`, label above some node at the same coordinated is above node border. for illustration compare `\node[label=A] at (1,1) {};` and `\coordinate[label=A] (A)( at (1,1);`. or i miss the point of your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference comes from the fact that a `\node` is not a zero-size object. It has an `inner sep`, which by default is 0.333em, so the width/height of an empty, default node, is 0.666em. This becomes obvious if you add `draw` to the node options.

If you use a `\coordinate[label=..` instead of a `\node` on the other hand, you get the same result. A `coordinate` is a special type of `node` used to give names to coordinates for reuse later, and where the size is zero, and all the anchors point to the `center` anchor.

The square in the image below is the node to which a label has been added. You can see where the difference comes from. What `above` does is just set `anchor=south`. But for the node the `south` anchor is placed at the specified coordinate, for the `label` the `south` anchor (of the label node) is placed at the `north` anchor of the parent node, which is centered on that same coordinate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
        \node[draw,label=above:A] (a) at (1,2) {};
        \node[above] at (a) {A};
        \node[draw,label=left:C] (c) at (2,2) {};
        \node[left] at (c) {C};

        \coordinate[label=above:A] (a) at (1,1);
        \node[above] at (a) {A};
        \coordinate[label=left:C] (c) at (2,1);
        \node[left] at (c) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't look like you can globally set the offset for `right`/`above`/etc., so if you've set `label distance=3mm` and want the same offset for a normal node, you need e.g. `above=3mm`.

Or you can load the `positioning` library and set `above=of <named coordinate>`, then you can set the default distance with `node distance`, like you did with `label distance`. Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        label distance=3mm,
        node distance=3mm
     ]
        \draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);

        % all three As end up in the same place
        \coordinate[label=above:A] (a) at (1,2);
        \node[above=of a] {A}; % positioning library
        \node[above=3mm] at (a) {A}; % standard above

        % same thing here, all Cs are in the same place
        \coordinate[label=left:C] (c) at (2,2);
        \node[left=of c] {C};
        \node[left=3mm] at (c) {C};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my example wasn't clear. I'm not trying to have a node labelled "A", then an extra label "B" above. I was just trying to show two different ways that I have seen used to add a label to a coordinate point, say, (1,1); and to show that the two methods do not yield the same result; and trying to understand why, and how to get the same results. If I can reformulate my question, it is: why doesn't `\node[above]  at (1,1) {A};` yields the same result as `\node[label=above:A] at (1,1) {};`. And how can we make it do?

Comment: @Peutch Right, will rewrite my answer.

Comment: @Peutch More useful now?